# Getting error SQLCODE = -805, ERROR: DBRM OR PACKAGE NAME Not found

Tags: db2, mainframe, jcl, unload

Getting error SQLCODE = -805, ERROR:  DBRM OR PACKAGE NAME DALLAS9..DSNTIAUL.184FA79814E1838D NOT FOUND IN PLAN COBDBSTR.REASON 01.

```
//DBULOAD JOB CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGLEVEL=(1,1), 
//           PRTY=15,REGION=4M                                  
//*                                                             
//JOBLIB DD DSN=DSN910.DB9G.SDSNEXIT,DISP=SHR                   
//       DD DSN=DSN910.SDSNLOAD,DISP=SHR                        
//UNLOAD EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,DYNAMNBR=50                          
//SYSIN DD *                                                    
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES ;                                
/*                                                              
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSTSIN DD *                                                  
DSN SYSTEM(DB9G)                                                
RUN PROGRAM(DSNTIAUL) -                                         
    PLAN(DSNTIAUL) - 
     LIB('DSN910.DB9G.RUNLIB.LOAD') -            
     PARMS('SQL')                                
 END                                             
 /*                                              
 //SYSREC00 DD DSN=RAHUL.TABLE.UNLOAD,           
 //            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),          
 //            UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(1,1),RLSE) 
 //*** TABLE STRUCTURE                           
 //SYSPUNCH DD DSN=RAHUL.TABLE.SYSPUNCH,         
 //            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),          
 //            UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(1,1),RLSE) 
 //*
```

I am running Db2 unload JCL and getting the above error. As per above error it is asking me to bind again. No idea where is DSNTIAUL dbrm module.

Getting same error again and again. It is a utility. My JCL completes with a 0012 error code . Please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into [DB2 Sql Error Code -805](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=codes-805).

-805 PACKAGE NAME *location-name*.*collection-id*.*dbrm-name*.*consistency-token* NOT FOUND IN PLAN *plan-name*. REASON *reason-code*

Where
location-name : DALLAS9
collection-id : NULL
dbrm-name : DSNTIAUL 
consistency-token: 184FA79814E1838D 
reason-code : 01
plan-name : COBDBSTR

Which means *The package name was not found because there is no package list for the plan.*
Verify it with query

```
SELECT LOCATION, COLLID, NAME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSPACKLIST
WHERE PLANNAME = 'COBDBSTR';
```

Contact DB2 admins asking them to *add the PKLIST option with the appropriate package list entry to the REBIND subcommand and rebind the application plan that is identified by name COBDBSTR*

Answer (score 0):

Got the correct plan from DB2ADM (DB2 administrator).